# How to save the last integer used in a for-loop

Tags: java, for-loop, save

I am currently working on a program where I need to save the value of the last integer used.

Let us consider this scenario:

```
   for (int i = 1;i<=28123;i++){
        if (isAbundant(i)){
            if (i*2 <= 28123){
                sum2 += i*2;
            }
            if (i + [the previous value of i] <= 28123){
                sum2 += i + [the previous value of i];
            }
        }
    }
```

How would I go about getting the `previous value of i` to actually represent the previous value of `i`? Do I need to save `i` as an another variable? If that is the case, wouldn't `i` just turn into the current `i`?

If you recognize the problem set this problem is from: Please do not comment regarding the problem itself. Please answer the question directly.

Comment: What about using some variable where you store the value?

Comment: define `int i;` before the `for-loop` and use it like this `for(i = 1;i<=28123;i++)` or `int i = 1;` + `for(;i<=28123;i++)` this way the variable `i` is visible outside the scope of the `for` block.

Answer (score 3):

despite the way in which the question was asked (manners cost nothing), define int i outside of the loop:

```
int i=0;
for (i = 1;i<=28123;i++){
    if (isAbundant(i)){
        if (i*2 <= 28123){
            sum2 += i*2;
        }
        if (i + (i-1) <= 28123) { //your only ++ing i, so previous value is always i-1
            sum2 += i + (i-1);
        }
    }
}

//i is now accessable here
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. You might, however, need to handle the special case of first iteration as per your requirement.

```
int pre = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= 28123; i++) {
    if (isAbundant(i)) {
        if (i * 2 <= 28123) {
            sum2 += i * 2;
        }
        if (i + pre <= 28123) {
            sum2 += i + pre;
        }
    }
    pre = i;
}
```

Comment: removed down vote as it was possibly a little harsh for what i gave it for. it was due to the unnecessary defining of pre, pre is completely superfluous in this instance and is only wasting processing time